# Finding specific elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following markup.

```
<h6>Brand</h6>

<ul>
    <li>Orange</li>
    <li>Black</li>
    <li>Green</li>
</ul>

<h6>Colour</h6>

<ul>
    <li>Green</li>
    <li>Blue</li>
    <li>Black</li>
    <li>Orange</li>
</ul>
```

I am unable to change or physically add into this markup, so hence trying to manipulate with jQuery.

What I want to achieve from this is to be able to change the word `Black` to `Purple`. But only the word `Black` that appears after the `H6` containing "Colour"

I have this so far:

```
$("h6:contains('Colour'):.jqueryCheck:contains('Black')").html("Purple");
```

This however does not work... Why not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$("h6:contains('Colour')").next('ul').children("li:contains('Black')").html("Purple");
```

Or all as one selector string:

```
$("h6:contains('Colour') + ul li:contains('Black')").html("Purple");
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using the [adjacent selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/):

```
$("h6:contains('Colour')+ ul li:contains('Black')").text('Purple');
```

See this *[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nmuDe/2/)*.

Comment: This will change both `li`s, he only wants the one after `<h6>Colour</h6>`.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I had previously, I only want to change one instance under the H6 containing Colour. Thaks for taking time though

Comment: @Rocket tnx for pointing that out fixed it, why ppl are so eager to give DV's

Answer (score 5):

You can use something like this:

```
$("h6:contains('Colour')").next().find("li:contains('Black')").text('Purple');​
```

This finds the appropriate `<h6>` that contains `"Colour"`, then advances to the next sibling (which is the `<ul>` tag, then inside that `<ul>`, it finds an `<li>` that contains `"Black"` and changes that text to `"Purple"`.

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/rdSzC/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('h6:contains("Colour")').next('ul').children('li:contains("Black")').text("Purple");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/yqneu/1/)